# Assigning R.id to each elements within an Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I created this ArrayList with Custom Adapter and ArrayList Data Type as show below,

```
ArrayList<Question> questionsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
questionsArrayList.add(new Question("Question 1:", "What is his Favorite Color?", "Blue", "Green", "Red"));
questionsArrayList.add(new Question("Question 2:", "What is his Favorite Band of All Time?", "Linkin Park", "Led Zeppelin", "My Chemical Romance"));
questionsArrayList.add(new Question("Question 3:", "Where is his place of birth?", "Calamba, Laguna", "Barangka, Marikina", "Sampaloc, Manila"));
questionsArrayList.add(new Question("Question 4:", "Is he handsome?", "Yes", "Hollie Macaroni", "I think so"));
```

Now my question is, is it possible to assign a resource id to particular elements of each Array? Let's say I want to assign a Resource Id to "Blue", "Led Zeppelin", "Barangka, Marikina", and "Hollie Macaroni".

Is it possible?
Thank You!

Comment: Yes, `R.id.someid` return a unique integer  which can be assigned to any `int` variable.

Comment: Thanks Jack!  I think you're right! R.id can be called through Int. I'll try to do some workaround on this.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to assign a resource id to particular elements of each Array?

You can Map an Integer (resource id) to a Question object, yes.

> Let's say I want to assign a Resource Id to "Blue", "Led Zeppelin", "Barangka, Marikina", and "Hollie Macaroni"

That sounds like you want R.string values, not R.id

Comment: Nice! I think I should pattern the custom array list type in an int instead of a String. I'm currently doing some workaround on this now.